# MEF dafault Import of base class

Tags: c#, mef

I have an employee object:

```
public class CreateEmployee 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Import(AllowDefault=true)]
    public ExtendEmployee ExtendEmployee { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendEmployee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to extend this ExtendEmployee during runtime using MEF.

```
[Export]
public class ExtendCreateEmployee : ExtendEmployee
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

> **My Question is**: If I dont define this [Export], is there a way to
>   import the base class "ExtendEmployee" instead of the default null for
>   the import.

I considered decorating the base class with [Export] attribute but in that case, the import will consider both the classes and I have to filter the inherited class. This can be fine if there is a way to either choose from the base class or the inherited class.

Thanks